# Google Sheets - Why are there garbage digits in MOD(??)&"*"?

Tags: google-sheets, modulo, google-workspace, unit-conversion

tl;dr - why am I getting these weird remainders in `MOD()&"*"`, which are not showing up in `MOD()`?

On behalf of an old-timey cheesemonger acquaintance of mine, I'm trying to convert a value **from** ounces to **pounds and ounces**. When I build a conversion formula, though, I am **sometimes** getting some weird remainders.

[image: Screengrab from Google Sheets]

- Column D is the source number of ounces.
- Column E is just `=MOD(D?)`
- Column F is `=MOD(D?)&" oz."`, but the content doesn't matter - any concatenation of that cell blows out a weird remainder...but only for some values?

Why is this happening? Is there a single-column method to fix this?

Comment: This is happening because of how floating point numbers are represented in binary (IEEE 754). If you increase the number of decimal places in column E you'll see the digits there too. Your best option is to round them away, as you've already discovered.

Comment: Well, if I had just RTFM...

From Google's documentation on `MOD()`:

The MOD function also applies on non-integer numbers but may result in an approximate result due to the use of floating point arithmetic. You can use the ROUND function to round the output up or down to get the expected result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I feel like I'm committing some kind of sin, but this seems to be gouda enough.

Column E now runs:

`=INT(D4/16)&" lb. "&ROUND(MOD(D4,16),1)&" oz."`

Comment: Gouda Enough is a pretty cheesy result, but glad you got there.